# Как правильно разбить компонент VueJS на html/css/js?

Tags: vue.js

Изучаю статью https://metanit.com/web/vuejs/7.1.php, в самом конце статьи, в разделе "Разделение компонента на части" - повторяю за автором статьи, пытаясь разбить `VueJS` компонент на `html/css/js`, а именно:

1. Выношу стили в отдельный `css` - работает.
2. Выношу скрипт в отдельный файл `js` - работает.
3. Выношу шаблон в отдельный файл `html` - ошибка.

**Работает:**

```
<template>
    <div id="app" class="class_123">
        <h2>{{message}}</h2>
    </div>
</template>
<style src="./modal.css"></style>
<script src="./modal.js"></script>
```

**Не работает:**

```
<template src="./modal.html"></template>
<style src="./modal.css"></style>
<script src="./modal.js"></script>
```

**Код `modal.html` в момент выноса в него шаблона:**

```
<div id="app" class="class_123">
    <h2>{{message}}</h2>
</div>
```

**При выносе кода шаблона в `modal.html` получаю ошибку:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Структура приложения:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопросы:**

1. Как правильно разбивать приложение `VueJS` на шаблон, скрипты и стили?
2. Правильно ли так разбивать приложение `VueJS`? Понятно, что малое приложение можно и не разбивать, а если оно большое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже для таких маленьких проектов желательно разделять на разные файлы, но когда ты будешь использовать vue cli, то это считается обязательным. css стиль надо подключать как обычно через link, а скрипт там где ты подключаешь уже vuejs то он должен находится на самом низу твоего проекта!

```
<body>
    <div>
        .....
    <div>
    <script src="modal.js"></script>
</body>
```